# In GIMP, how to stroke a selection or a path with gradient?

Tags: gimp

I need the edge of mask to be fuzzy. The ways i found to do this is either by feather a selection or by stroking a selection with a fuzzy brush. But i need to define the edge transition more specificly. Ideally to create a custom gradient and use it for the edge.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Your question is a bit confusing - you ask about stroking with a gradient, but the main body text suggests you want the edges of a mask to be fuzzy. Can you perhaps edit your question, and also mention what you have tried or show an image of what you are trying to achieve? If you want a fuzzy layer mask you could just blur it slightly, or feather a selection before filling it.  Also note that there's no such thing as a "gradient pattern" - those are two different things in GIMP.

Comment: @BillyKerr the question is about stroking with a gradient, and the main body simply explains what it is for - to create edge transition. It also explains why feathering a selection is not an option.  By gradient pattern i meant a custom gradient, i will clear this part of the question. thanks.

Comment: You can make custom gradients with [the gradient editor](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-gradient-dialog.html#gimp-gradient-editor-dialog) - in combination with xenoid's answer, this should enable you to do what you want, as far as I can tell without seeing an image or example.

Answer (score 1):

See the [`ofn-gradient-along-path` script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/), in combination with a selection from the path to keep only the inner/outer half.

You can also use a plain gradient, and use Levels/Curves to alter it (if it's a selection do this with the "QuickMask".